# How to load child object from parent class object in java

Tags: java, hibernate, class, jakarta-ee, inheritance

I have this classes

`interface UserInterface`

Then

`abstract class user implements UserInterface`

Then i have two child classes

`Class Teacher extends User`

`Class Parent extends User`

Now in the dtabase i have three tables

1. `user table with id,password`
2. `teacher with FK and other stuff`
3. `parent with FK and other stuff`

Now i am checking the login using User class.

My problem is that if Employee logins then the object in memory will be of User type. How can then i get the Employee object

Is my model wrong and i need to do different way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming Employee is a third subclass of User, then if a user logs in, and you get this user from the database using Hibernate, and this user is in fact an employee, then Hibernate will return an Employee instance. It works as you would expect.

If it doesn't, then you did something wrong, but it's impossible to tell without seeing the code.

Answer (score 0):

If you ask hibernate for an Object of type `User`, you will always end up with a `UserEnhancedByCGLib` (or something similar). You cannot (by principle) cast that one down to a `Teacher` or a `Parent`.

You have two choices solving that issue.

1) You know at the time of login that a user is actually Teacher/Parent, than you initially ask hibernate for a Teacher/Parent object instead of a User object.

2) You don't know at the time of login, than you have to live with the User object and do a second query to the database once you actually need the specialization to teacher/parent.

One way to do number 2 is:

```
public Object refresh(Object object) {
    if (object != null) {
        if (object instanceof HibernateProxy) {
            return ((HibernateProxy) object).getHibernateLazyInitializer().getImplementation();
        }
    }
    return object;
}
```

Which will (if memory serves) give you the concrete class but a detached object.